Can you find a grand tour of the rooms in this 12x12 grid?

Puzzle maven Nob Yoshigahara offered this puzzle in the September-October 2000 issue of MIT Technology Review, attributing it to a Professor Kotani. In the 4x4 complex of rooms above, two of the rooms are closed. This leaves a single way to tour the remaining rooms in a series of orthogonal moves, visiting each room once and returning to the starting point.
The 12x12 complex below has a similarly unique solution. What is it?

Attribution:  Nob Yoshigahara and futilitycloset.com

This kind of puzzle reminds me of the now-defunct Alcazar puzzle app.

Solution with a solve path (Solve it yourself on Penpa+)
Let's construct some rules to help us solve.

Corner rule: in the following configuration, where * denotes no connection and   denotes an unknown connection

    B
     
X * A   C
    *
    Y 

then the cells ("in the corner") must be connected, so you can draw the two line segments B-A and A-C, giving
    B
    |
X * A - C
    *
    Y 

Applying the corner rule and easy logic to the starting position gets us
(1)

 

The bottom left can only be resolved like this. Use the corner rule as well.
(2)

 

Invalid configuration rule: if there is a cell only reachable from one neighbour, then we have an invalid configuration.
Short loop avoidance rule: in the following configuration
    B
     
X   A   C
    *
    Y 

where X and C belong to the same short loop, we cannot have X-A and A-C. Therefore B-A is connected (to avoid triggering the invalid configuration rule). So
    B
    |
X   A   C
    *
    Y 

Using this, we can make some deductions.
(3) (The red segment leads to a quick contradiction and must be removed)

 

(4)

 

Connecting the red line leads to a contradiction in the top right after around 10 moves (see the comments under the other answer for a more elegant method). So we have
(5)

 

Connecting the red line leads to a contradiction in the middle right after around 11 moves. So we have
(6)

 

Connecting some obvious things (starting from the bottom) leads to
(7)

 

Avoiding a big loop on the left leads to the solution
(8)

 



 Solving squares with just two neighbours and avoiding short loops will get you this far:

 The squares surrounded by three crosses have three possibilities for the loop, but for each square one of those possibilities makes a short loop and the other two share a common edge. We can fill in those common edges:
 
 Repeat this line of reasoning, remembering to always put forced edges after an assumption to see if a contradiction arises. Then we can positively fill in some more edges:
 
 The puzzle now essentially solves itself through zigzags (diagonal lines of squares with only two vacant neighbours).
 
 These pictures were made on puzz.link.


I don’t quite understand short loops and one-move lookahead.  Could you please explain these concepts in more detail preferably with visual examples.  Thanks!

In my solve path I had to do something like a 10-move lookahead. If you have any pointers on my answer I'd appreciate it.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson 'One-move lookahead' consider a shape like | _ _ |, there are three of them after step (1) in Benjamin Wang's solve. Take the square on the 'inside' of the U shape. There are six possible paths through that square. Three of them intersect the U that is already present, one of them complete the U into a short loop. The two remaining paths both share the component leading away from the U, so we can fill it in. I can confirm that one-step lookaheads like this are sufficient to solve the puzzle. This type of puzzle is called 'Slitherlink', usually with clues given.

@BradyGilg the U shape (I called this "short loop avoidance rule") helps a little with reducing the search. Slitherlink seems much easier than this puzzle. Do you see any way to avoid the big look aheads in step 4 and step 5 in my solution?

@BenjaminWang Yes, the link in blue is the most helpful next deduction as an alternative to the red in step (4). https://i.sstatic.net/tCe58Tqy.png It is a 'one-step lookahead', consider what would happen if the path through that square were formed from the other two possible links instead. A loop is created one step later.

@BenjaminWang This is the board state if you attempt to use the other two paths. You can see there is an immediate problem. https://i.sstatic.net/vTnWD8Uo.png

I see. If a square has 3 possible connections and none are connected yet, then it is easier to consider whether the absence of a certain connection would lead to a contradiction.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson done.

@ParclyTaxel +1 This is better now!
